# Использование прокси в aiohttp

Tags: python, proxy, asyncio, aiohttp

Друзья, возник вопрос.

Использую [документацию](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#proxy-support) , хочу отправлять запросы с разных адресов.

Получился следующий код

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp


sites = [
    'https://ifconfig.me/ip',
    'https://ifconfig.me/ip',
    'https://ifconfig.me/ip',
]

proxys = [
    'https://proxy:port',
    'https://proxy:port',
    'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
    # 'https://proxy:port',
]


async def fetch(session, url):
    proxy_auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth('login', 'password')
    async with session.get(url[0], timeout=3, proxy=url[1], proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as resp:
        print(resp)
        if resp.ok:
            result = await resp.read()
            print(result)
        else:
            print("\n!MISSED!\n")


async def func():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        x = list(zip(sites, proxys))
        html_links = [fetch(session, url) for url in x]
        return await asyncio.gather(*html_links)



asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(func())
```

Получаю в ответ

**raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None**

**asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError**

Почитав в интернете понял что проблема может быть из-за того что нет поддержки https прокси. Мои прокси именно такие, но разве https не предполагает наличие http, подумал я - и стер все s-ки из proxys. В ответ получил **raise ClientHttpProxyError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientHttpProxyError: 502, message='Bad Gateway', url=URL('http://proxy:port')**

В документации есть сноска [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/discussions/6044#discussioncomment-1432443

Но и предоставленное решение не смогло меня удовлетворить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Что я понял?*** Либо моих умений искать информацию недостаточно, либо я где-то в корне налажал/не понял/не разобрался.

***Что я хочу?*** Хочу чтобы разработчики, которые сталкивались с такой же проблемой или же разработчики, решившие мою задачу другим способом, поделились своим опытом/натолкнули на мысль.

***Требования для решения моей задачи.*** Я видел что обычные requests вроде как умеют стучаться на https сайт по https прокси, но у меня будет много запросов и очень ценно время за которое программа их выполнит, именно поэтому использую асинхронность. Наверно можно подумать о вэбсокете, но основная логика уже реализована на асинхронных запросах, поэтому хочется рассмотреть все возможные варианты решения, прежде чем глобально переписывать код.

Буду рад любым конструктивным комментариям и ответам.

Заранее спасибо.

**Изменено**:

Спрашивали, что будет если убрать параметр `timeout`. Вместо +/-3 секунд придется подождать гораздо больше. И будет следующая ошибка

> ***ConnectionAbortedError: SSL handshake is taking longer than 60.0 seconds: aborting the connection***
>
> ***raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientProxyConnectionError: Cannot connect
> to host proxy:port ssl:default [None]***

Comment: @Стас этот параметр отвечает за то, сколько программа будет ждать ответа от каждой открытой сессии. Его можно убрать, да, но просто ошибка появится следующего типа *ConnectionAbortedError: SSL handshake is taking longer than 60.0 seconds: aborting the connection*. То есть какое-то есть, но поэтому соединению ничего не идет. Я мог предположить, что ошибка в том как я читаю информацию(`.json()`, `.read()` или же `.text()`), но у меня добавлена строчка `print(resp)`, которая ничего не выводит, даже не объект какой-нибудь, что означает что соединение не идет. Тут круг замыкается. Дополню вопрос.

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример воспроизводящий ошибку или тестовый пример, разместите полную трассировку ошибки. Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о системе, о используемом прокси и др. подробности для того, чтоб можно было дать адекватный ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @СергейКох минимальный пример уже приведен. Информация о моих прокси тоже предоставлена. Если вы хотите чтобы я предоставил адреса с портами с логином и паролем, то уж извините я не буду этого делать. Я же задавал вопрос тем, кто уже сталкивался с такой ошибкой. Очень интересно смотреть на полную трассировку, ведь она же начинается с вызова main и заканчивается на fetch. Безусловно рад вашему интересу, но я убежден, что информации я предоставил достаточно. Конечно всегда легче проголосовать против и сказать, что вам не все ясно в проблеме с которой вы не сталкивались, чем просто пройти мимо)

Comment: Добрый день. Проблема так и не решилась? Столкнулся с ней же, могли бы вы поделиться результатами/решением ?